# ASP.NET unknown output exception and message connecting SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, html

I created a new website. I added a web form `Default2.aspx` in which I created a gridview by dragging it from Tool box. then added the following code for

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"><Columns>
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email" >
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:Label ID="lbl_Email" Text='<%# Bind("User_Email")%>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
 </ItemTemplate>
 <ItemStyle Font-Size="15px" />
 </asp:TemplateField>
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name" >
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:Label ID="lbl_first_name" Text='<%# Bind("User_First_Name")%>'   runat="server">     </asp:Label>
 </ItemTemplate>
 <ItemStyle Font-Size="15px" />
 </asp:TemplateField>
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Name" >
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:Label ID="lbl_last_name" CssClass="aLinkButton" Text='<%# Bind("User_Last_Name")%>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
 </ItemTemplate>
 <ItemStyle Font-Size="15px" />
 </asp:TemplateField>
 </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Then in the `aspx.cs` page I added the following code to bind the table to my gridview1

```
public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   string strcon = "Server=BLR-MTP-IBM-91;Database=IBM;Trusted_Connection=True;";
// connection string //

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
// opened connection

SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(); // for query

DataSet ds = new DataSet();

SqlDataAdapter da;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        bindgrid();
    }
}

private void bindgrid()
{
    ds.Clear();
    con.ConnectionString = strcon;
    com.Connection = con;
    con.Open();

    string strquery = "select * from users;";

    da = new SqlDataAdapter(strquery, con);

    da.Fill(ds);

    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    con.Close();

    }
}
```

In my SQL Server 2008 R2 I created a database called `IBM` and a table with column names as

```
User_Email, User_First_Name, User_Last_Name
```

There is no error showing up in error window. In the output window I can see the following messages:

I had many removed few by TOOlS - Options - Debugging - delete Break Points &
Enable Just my code. I removed some But i am not sure. what is the problem. I am a new bie. Breaking my head a long time. finally came to stack overflow fro solution.

> 'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'
>   'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Program
>   Files\Common Files\Microsoft
>   Shared\DevServer\10.0\WebDev.WebServer40.exe' 'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE'
>   (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\WebDev.WebHost40\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\WebDev.WebHost40.dll'
>   'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'
>   'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'
>   'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'
>   'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll'
>   'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'
>   'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'
>   'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'
>   'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Caching\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.Caching.dll'
>   'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0.dll' 'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.RegularExpressions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.RegularExpressions.dll'
>   'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Design\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Design.dll'
>   'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Build.Framework\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.Build.Framework.dll'
>   'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'
>   'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll'
>   'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll'
>   'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll'
>   'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Numerics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Numerics.dll'
>   'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.JScript\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.JScript.dll'
>   'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll'
>   'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\website4\e495d551\13a31e82\App_global.asax.9ug4n6nu.dll',
>   Symbols loaded. 'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)):
>   Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mobile\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Mobile.dll'
>   'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activation\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll'
>   'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll'
>   'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll'
>   'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\SMDiagnostics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\SMDiagnostics.dll'
>   'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.DurableInstancing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Runtime.DurableInstancing.dll'
>   'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xaml.Hosting\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Xaml.Hosting.dll'
>   'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll'
>   'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll'
>   'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll'
>   'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll'
>   'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll'
>   'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Activities.dll'
>   'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activities.dll'
>   'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll'
>   'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll'
>   'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll'
>   'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll'
>   'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.DynamicData\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.DynamicData.dll'
>   'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll'
>   'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\website4\e495d551\13a31e82\App_Web_wzu153su.dll', Symbols
>   loaded. 'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'A_e34e3632_6676_413f_a677_eaf48e7b990b' 'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE'
>   (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Entity\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Web.Entity.dll'
>   'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.Services.Design\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.Services.Design.dll'
>   'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\website4\e495d551\13a31e82\App_Web_tn3t0nc2.dll', Symbols
>   loaded. 'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll'
>   'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\website4\e495d551\13a31e82\App_Web_vccklmdo.dll', Symbols
>   loaded. The program '[3668] WebDev.WebServer40.EXE: Managed
>   (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: Do you get an error message anywhere? In that case what is it? The output window contents you've included are just standard messages of dlls being loaded - they say nothing.

Comment: there is no error messages showing up. the web page when it loads it is blank. I donot see the grid.

Answer (score 2):

Try to split our code in chunks, first see whether you are able to get your db connection? if its done successfully than go for data retrieval . and once you are done with that than go for data binding.

Comment: public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page { protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        string connString = "server= BLR-MTP-IBM-91;database=IBM;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString); 
try {
        conn.Open();
          Label1.Text = "Connection opened";
      }catch (SqlException a) {         Console.WriteLine("Error: " + a);     }
      finally {
         conn.Close();
         Label2.Text = "Connection Closed";
      }}
    } the above code prints as i taught. so i am able to connect to DB. not able to retrive now.

Comment: ok, try this instead of template field <Columns>
                           <asp:BoundField DataField="User_Email" HeaderText="User_Email" 
                                 />
                               <asp:BoundField DataField="User_First_Name" HeaderText="User_First_Name" 
                                />
                                
                                  <asp:BoundField DataField="User_Last_Name" HeaderText="User_Last_Name" 
                                 />
                        
                          
                        </Columns>

Answer (score 0):

What database do you use? This connection string doesn't look like an sql server one.
It should look like: Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True

If you are sure that you have the proper connection, try to remove from the gridView the templates. Leave the default, empty gridView control. When the data comes, the grid should display everything the dataset holds. I tried it right now with the sql server and it work.

If it won't work, I assume something with the connection to db is wrong. But some error should be thrown I guess. Of course in your test table you have any data? ;)

Do you see an empty grid table in the page source? Is it rendered?

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
string strquery = "SELECT * FROM users"
```